# Change edge thickness with tkplot (Igraph, R)

Tags: r, igraph, tkplot

I was wondering if there is a way to change the edge thickness when using `tkplot()`

I know you can do it by right clicking the edge and changing it manually, but I would like to be able to call up an attribute to use for the edge. Similar to when using the normal plot function in igraph where I can do `edge.width=E(g)$Weight`

Also, is there a way to save the tkplot as a png without the use of other packages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can change the edge width, actually it works exactly the same way as for `plot()`.

The Tk canvas does not support the PNG format, so you cannot save `tkplot()` output in PNG. If you use `tkplot()` for adjusting coordinates, then use `tkplot.getcoords()` to query the adjusted coordinates and then use `plot()` with these coordinates to create the PNG file.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(10)
id <- tkplot(g, edge.width=1:10)
## Now adjust the coordinates by hand, and then continue.
## E.g. I moved vertex 7 to the middle
co <- tkplot.getcoords(id)
png("output.png")
plot(g, layout=co, edge.width=1:10)
dev.off()
```

[image: example output figure]

Comment: Which one? The edge width or `tkplot.getcoords`? Anyway, I'll show them both in a sec.